# Should Service Layer methods expect instances or id's?

Tags: design-patterns, grails, web-applications, service-layer

This question arised from my work on a Grails application, but it applies to pretty much every web application developed in layers. Here's a simple example:

```
class OrderService {

    // Option 1
    def shipOrder(Order order) {
        order.status = OrderStatus.SHIPPED
        emailService.sendShipmentEmail(order)
        // ...
    }

    // Option 2
    def shipOrder(long orderId) {
        def order = Order.get(orderId)
        order.status = OrderStatus.SHIPPED
        emailService.sendShipmentEmail(order)
        // ...
    }

}
```

Is any of these options documented as being better than the other one?

Comment: As always with these kinds of questions, it depends.  This is not a good question for SO and will likely be closed.

Comment: Hm, didn't realize that. I changed the question a little to make it less dependent on opinion.

Answer (score 9):

I tend to prefer ids, since you sometimes want to use pessimistic locking, and then it's easy to change `Order.get(orderId)` to `Order.lock(orderId)`. Locking has to happen in a transaction, so using the first approach you'd lock after reading, running the small risk of update in-between.

Sometimes it's necessary to load the instance outside of the service, e.g. to test for existence in the controller, so the second approach can feel like it wastes a database call. But you can change the `get()` call to an `exists()` call and only check for the existence of the id, rather than loading the entire instance just to see if it's there.

Note that you should use `long orderId` in your method signature since allowing a null id doesn't make sense.

Comment: +1 Absolute postmortem of the use case. Especially `exists()`, I see that a lot in my workplace. :)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't knew about `exists()`.

Comment: Me neither. Also, I heard Groovy treated long and Long the same (differently from Java). Now I just confirmed that long can't be null, indeed! Changed the code above. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréValenti Objects can be null, primitive datatypes cannot. If you provide `Long id` there is a possibility of `id` being sent as `null`. The possibility is eradicated when `long id` is used.

Comment: @dmahapatro I knew Java was that way, but thought Groovy treated everything as objects.

Comment: It does, but it really just autoboxes for you (even in 1.4 before it was available in Java). So for example you can call methods on primitives (e.g. 4.times { ... } ). But it doesn't extend to nullability - you cannot have a null primitive.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Now that's a peculiar behavior!